# Error while converting base64 string

Tags: c#, base64

I am trying to convert a base64 string to HTML code which i am getting from my e-mail through Gmail Api in WinRT. But the problem is that while converting the base64 string to byte array, an FormatException is thrown.Also when i decoded it on the [base64decode](https://www.base64decode.org/) website, it perfectly decodes the base64 string.

This is the base64 string which i am trying to decode:

> PGltZyBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9jY3Byb21haWwuY29tOjgxODEvYWRtaW1wLmpzcD9pZD1UaUUtbldrcGhESUJuaHNUS2t0NENpclQzTHVvY09ZOVV2czJDb1lFbGo4YjZJWjl0TWp6SzNvRUpERkVHZnBnIiBib3JkZXI9IjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjAiPjxkaXYgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjYwMHB4OyAgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZjsgZm9udC1zaXplOiAxOHB4OyBsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoyMnB4OyB0ZXh0LWFsaWduOiBjZW50ZXI7Ij4gIDxmb250IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXdlaWdodDogYm9sZDsgZm9udC1zaXplOiAyMHB4OyBjb2xvcjogcmVkOyI-IEdST1cgWU9VUiBPV04gSEFJUiBGT1IgSlVTVCAxIFJTLjwvZm9udD4gIDxicj4gIDxicj4gIDxmb250IHN0eWxlPSJjb2xvcjpncmVlbjtmb250LXdlaWdodDogYm9sZDsiPkludGVyZXN0IEZyZWUgRU1JPGJyPjxicj4xIFJzLiBEb3duIFBheW1lbnQ8L2ZvbnQ-ICA8YnI-ICA8YnI-ICA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vY2Nwcm9tYWlsLmNvbTo4MTgxL3RyYWNrLmpzcD9pZD1UaUUtbldrcGhESUJuaHNUS2t0NENpclQzTHVvY09ZOVV2czJDb1lFbGo4YjZJWjl0TWp6SzNvRUpERkVHZnBnIiBzdHlsZT0iY29sb3I6IGJsdWU7IGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6IHllbGxvdzsiPkdldCBZb3VyIEFwcG9pbnRtZW50IE5vdzwvYT4gIDxicj4gIDxicj4gPC9kaXY-PGJyLz48ZGl2IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6OXB4O3dpZHRoOjYwMHB4O21hcmdpbi1sZWZ0OiAxNTBweDsiPjxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9jY3Byb21haWwuY29tOjgxODEvdHJhY2suanNwP2lkPVRpRS1uV2twaERJQm5oc1RLa3Q0Q2lyVDNMdW9jT1k5VXZzMkNvWUVsajhiNklaOXRNanpLM29FSkRGRUdmcGcmdT1hIj5DbGljayBIZXJlPC9hPiB0byB1bnN1YnNjcmliZSBmcm9tIHRoaXMgbmV3c2xldHRlci48YnIvPjwvZGl2Pg0K

EDIT:
This is the code that i am using to decode the string:

```
string raw = "PGltZyBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9jY3Byb21haWwuY29tOjgxODEvYWRtaW1wLmpzcD9pZD1UaUUtbldrcGhESUJuaHNUS2t0NENpclQzTHVvY09ZOVV2czJDb1lFbGo4YjZJWjl0TWp6SzNvRUpERkVHZnBnIiBib3JkZXI9IjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjAiPjxkaXYgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjYwMHB4OyAgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZjsgZm9udC1zaXplOiAxOHB4OyBsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoyMnB4OyB0ZXh0LWFsaWduOiBjZW50ZXI7Ij4gIDxmb250IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXdlaWdodDogYm9sZDsgZm9udC1zaXplOiAyMHB4OyBjb2xvcjogcmVkOyI-IEdST1cgWU9VUiBPV04gSEFJUiBGT1IgSlVTVCAxIFJTLjwvZm9udD4gIDxicj4gIDxicj4gIDxmb250IHN0eWxlPSJjb2xvcjpncmVlbjtmb250LXdlaWdodDogYm9sZDsiPkludGVyZXN0IEZyZWUgRU1JPGJyPjxicj4xIFJzLiBEb3duIFBheW1lbnQ8L2ZvbnQ-ICA8YnI-ICA8YnI-ICA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vY2Nwcm9tYWlsLmNvbTo4MTgxL3RyYWNrLmpzcD9pZD1UaUUtbldrcGhESUJuaHNUS2t0NENpclQzTHVvY09ZOVV2czJDb1lFbGo4YjZJWjl0TWp6SzNvRUpERkVHZnBnIiBzdHlsZT0iY29sb3I6IGJsdWU7IGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6IHllbGxvdzsiPkdldCBZb3VyIEFwcG9pbnRtZW50IE5vdzwvYT4gIDxicj4gIDxicj4gPC9kaXY-PGJyLz48ZGl2IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6OXB4O3dpZHRoOjYwMHB4O21hcmdpbi1sZWZ0OiAxNTBweDsiPjxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9jY3Byb21haWwuY29tOjgxODEvdHJhY2suanNwP2lkPVRpRS1uV2twaERJQm5oc1RLa3Q0Q2lyVDNMdW9jT1k5VXZzMkNvWUVsajhiNklaOXRNanpLM29FSkRGRUdmcGcmdT1hIj5DbGljayBIZXJlPC9hPiB0byB1bnN1YnNjcmliZSBmcm9tIHRoaXMgbmV3c2xldHRlci48YnIvPjwvZGl2Pg0K";
string codedbody = raw.Replace("-", "+");
codedbody = raw.Replace("_", "/");
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(codedbody);
string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: Show code, how you decode.

Comment: Your base64 string seems incomplete. => https://www.base64decode.org returns an incomplete HTML. Other decoders crashes and returns nothing.

Comment: your base64 string is malformed.

Comment: That's not "standard" [Base 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Unfortunately, I can't work out which variant it is since the only non-alphanumeric character I can see is `-`, and different variants assign different meanings to that character.

Comment: check to see if it is a base64 url encoded string

Comment: @Nkosi   How to check for it ?

Comment: Re: your code. You're doing two `Replace` calls but you're effectively throwing away the result of the first one when you probably intended to use it as the "source" for the second one (instead, you used `raw` again)

Comment: Notepad++ can do base 64 url encoding/decoding. The code in [this post](https://brockallen.com/2014/10/17/base64url-encoding/) may be what you need to do. Also note the Edit at the bottom.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever     Your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
string input = "PGltZyBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9jY3Byb21haWwuY29tOjgxODEvYWRtaW1wLmpzcD9pZD1UaUUtbldrcGhESUJuaHNUS2t0NENpclQzTHVvY09ZOVV2czJDb1lFbGo4YjZJWjl0TWp6SzNvRUpERkVHZnBnIiBib3JkZXI9IjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjAiPjxkaXYgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjYwMHB4OyAgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZjsgZm9udC1zaXplOiAxOHB4OyBsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoyMnB4OyB0ZXh0LWFsaWduOiBjZW50ZXI7Ij4gIDxmb250IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXdlaWdodDogYm9sZDsgZm9udC1zaXplOiAyMHB4OyBjb2xvcjogcmVkOyI-IEdST1cgWU9VUiBPV04gSEFJUiBGT1IgSlVTVCAxIFJTLjwvZm9udD4gIDxicj4gIDxicj4gIDxmb250IHN0eWxlPSJjb2xvcjpncmVlbjtmb250LXdlaWdodDogYm9sZDsiPkludGVyZXN0IEZyZWUgRU1JPGJyPjxicj4xIFJzLiBEb3duIFBheW1lbnQ8L2ZvbnQ-ICA8YnI-ICA8YnI-ICA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vY2Nwcm9tYWlsLmNvbTo4MTgxL3RyYWNrLmpzcD9pZD1UaUUtbldrcGhESUJuaHNUS2t0NENpclQzTHVvY09ZOVV2czJDb1lFbGo4YjZJWjl0TWp6SzNvRUpERkVHZnBnIiBzdHlsZT0iY29sb3I6IGJsdWU7IGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6IHllbGxvdzsiPkdldCBZb3VyIEFwcG9pbnRtZW50IE5vdzwvYT4gIDxicj4gIDxicj4gPC9kaXY-PGJyLz48ZGl2IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6OXB4O3dpZHRoOjYwMHB4O21hcmdpbi1sZWZ0OiAxNTBweDsiPjxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9jY3Byb21haWwuY29tOjgxODEvdHJhY2suanNwP2lkPVRpRS1uV2twaERJQm5oc1RLa3Q0Q2lyVDNMdW9jT1k5VXZzMkNvWUVsajhiNklaOXRNanpLM29FSkRGRUdmcGcmdT1hIj5DbGljayBIZXJlPC9hPiB0byB1bnN1YnNjcmliZSBmcm9tIHRoaXMgbmV3c2xldHRlci48YnIvPjwvZGl2Pg0K";
string result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(System.Convert.FromBase64String(input.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/")));
```

I kept your replacements because `-` and `_` are invalid characters for BASE64

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt to decode looks like you are trying to decode a base64 URL encoded string.

```
public byte[] Decode(string text) {
    var output = text;
    output = output.Replace('-', '+'); // 62nd char of encoding
    output = output.Replace('_', '/'); // 63rd char of encoding
    switch (output.Length % 4) { // Pad with trailing '='s
        case 0: break; // No pad chars in this case
        case 2: output += "=="; break; // Two pad chars
        case 3: output += "="; break;  // One pad char
        default: throw new FormatException("invalid format", text));
    }
    var converted = Convert.FromBase64String(output); // Standard base64 decoder
    return converted;
}
```

With the above code you can do

```
string raw = "PGltZyBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9jY3Byb21haWwuY29tOjgxODEvYWRtaW1wLmpzcD9pZD1UaUUtbldrcGhESUJuaHNUS2t0NENpclQzTHVvY09ZOVV2czJDb1lFbGo4YjZJWjl0TWp6SzNvRUpERkVHZnBnIiBib3JkZXI9IjAiIGhlaWdodD0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjAiPjxkaXYgc3R5bGU9IndpZHRoOjYwMHB4OyAgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsIEhlbHZldGljYSwgc2Fucy1zZXJpZjsgZm9udC1zaXplOiAxOHB4OyBsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoyMnB4OyB0ZXh0LWFsaWduOiBjZW50ZXI7Ij4gIDxmb250IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXdlaWdodDogYm9sZDsgZm9udC1zaXplOiAyMHB4OyBjb2xvcjogcmVkOyI-IEdST1cgWU9VUiBPV04gSEFJUiBGT1IgSlVTVCAxIFJTLjwvZm9udD4gIDxicj4gIDxicj4gIDxmb250IHN0eWxlPSJjb2xvcjpncmVlbjtmb250LXdlaWdodDogYm9sZDsiPkludGVyZXN0IEZyZWUgRU1JPGJyPjxicj4xIFJzLiBEb3duIFBheW1lbnQ8L2ZvbnQ-ICA8YnI-ICA8YnI-ICA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vY2Nwcm9tYWlsLmNvbTo4MTgxL3RyYWNrLmpzcD9pZD1UaUUtbldrcGhESUJuaHNUS2t0NENpclQzTHVvY09ZOVV2czJDb1lFbGo4YjZJWjl0TWp6SzNvRUpERkVHZnBnIiBzdHlsZT0iY29sb3I6IGJsdWU7IGJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3I6IHllbGxvdzsiPkdldCBZb3VyIEFwcG9pbnRtZW50IE5vdzwvYT4gIDxicj4gIDxicj4gPC9kaXY-PGJyLz48ZGl2IHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXNpemU6OXB4O3dpZHRoOjYwMHB4O21hcmdpbi1sZWZ0OiAxNTBweDsiPjxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9jY3Byb21haWwuY29tOjgxODEvdHJhY2suanNwP2lkPVRpRS1uV2twaERJQm5oc1RLa3Q0Q2lyVDNMdW9jT1k5VXZzMkNvWUVsajhiNklaOXRNanpLM29FSkRGRUdmcGcmdT1hIj5DbGljayBIZXJlPC9hPiB0byB1bnN1YnNjcmliZSBmcm9tIHRoaXMgbmV3c2xldHRlci48YnIvPjwvZGl2Pg0K";
byte[] data = Decode(raw);
string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

which produces html output

```
<img src="http://ccpromail.com:8181/admimp.jsp?id=TiE-nWkphDIBnhsTKkt4CirT3LuocOY9Uvs2CoYElj8b6IZ9tMjzK3oEJDFEGfpg" border="0" height="0" width="0"><div style="width:600px;  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height:22px; text-align: center;">  <font style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; color: red;"> GROW YOUR OWN HAIR FOR JUST 1 RS.</font>  <br>  <br>  <font style="color:green;font-weight: bold;">Interest Free EMI<br><br>1 Rs. Down Payment</font>  <br>  <br>  <a href="http://ccpromail.com:8181/track.jsp?id=TiE-nWkphDIBnhsTKkt4CirT3LuocOY9Uvs2CoYElj8b6IZ9tMjzK3oEJDFEGfpg" style="color: blue; background-color: yellow;">Get Your Appointment Now</a>  <br>  <br> </div><br/><div style="font-size:9px;width:600px;margin-left: 150px;"><a href="http://ccpromail.com:8181/track.jsp?id=TiE-nWkphDIBnhsTKkt4CirT3LuocOY9Uvs2CoYElj8b6IZ9tMjzK3oEJDFEGfpg&u=a">Click Here</a> to unsubscribe from this newsletter.<br/></div>
```

> URL applications
>
> Base64 encoding can be helpful when fairly lengthy identifying
>   information is used in an HTTP environment. For example, a database
>   persistence framework for Java objects might use Base64 encoding to
>   encode a relatively large unique id (generally 128-bit UUIDs) into a
>   string for use as an HTTP parameter in HTTP forms or HTTP GET URLs.
>   Also, many applications need to encode binary data in a way that is
>   convenient for inclusion in URLs, including in hidden web form fields,
>   and Base64 is a convenient encoding to render them in a compact way.
>
> Using standard Base64 in URL requires encoding of '+', '/' and '='
>   characters into special percent-encoded hexadecimal sequences ('+'
>   becomes '%2B', '/' becomes '%2F' and '=' becomes '%3D'), which makes
>   the string unnecessarily longer.
>
> For this reason, modified Base64 for URL variants exist, where the '+'
>   and '/' characters of standard Base64 are respectively replaced by '-'
>   and '_', so that using URL encoders/decoders is no longer necessary
>   and have no impact on the length of the encoded value, leaving the
>   same encoded form intact for use in relational databases, web forms,
>   and object identifiers in general. Some variants allow or require
>   omitting the padding '=' signs to avoid them being confused with field
>   separators, or require that any such padding be percent-encoded. Some
>   libraries (like org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.UrlBase64Encoder) will
>   encode '=' to '.'.

Reference [Base64 : From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Answer (score 1):

You make mistake in your code:
You again take to replace `raw` instead `codebody`

```
codedbody = raw.Replace("_", "/");
```

Should be:

```
codedbody = codedbody.Replace("_", "/");
```